# Rationale behind scope resolution in strongly typed enumerations

Tags: c++, enums, c++11

What is the rationale behind unconditionally requiring explicit scope resolution in strongly typed enumerations?

N2347 explains the difference to old-fashion enumerations which are absence of implicit conversion, ability to specify storage type, and no injection of names in the surrounding scope (as in C++03, which has that as a heritage of C).

In other words, writing `enum E1 { a, b, c};` as in C++03 is similar to writing

```
const int a = 1; const int b = 2; const int c = 3;
```

whereas `enum E1 class { a, b, c};` as in C++11 is much more similar to something like

```
namespace E1 { const int a = 1; const int b = 2; const int c = 3; }
```

(without introducing a namespace, and with defining an enum type in either case).

Now, I generally don't understand where there is an ambiguity, assuming one has for example code like the following (which won't compile):

```
enum class E1 { a, b, c };
enum class E2 { a, b, c }; // allowed now

void foo(E1 e) { ... }
void bar(E2 e) { ... }
void baz(int e) { ... }

foo(a);   // not ambigious: E1 expected, nothing but E1::a possible
bar(a);   // not ambigious: E2 expected, nothing but E2::a possible
baz(a);   // not ambigious: illegal - no name `a` in global scope

E1 x = a; // not ambigious: E1 expected, nothing but E1::a possible
```

I welcome (optional) explicit scope resolution in some cases to point out what's going on, but I do not understand why C++11 requires explicit scope resolution, even when there is no possible way of interpreting code in another way.

It would in my opinion be reasonable to expect that for example `void foo(E1 e);` has a meaning much more like `void foo(using enum E1; E1 e);` (my syntax is of course totally wrong, but you get the idea).

Taking the "classic" example of `Color` and `Alert`that is also in N2347, one has *red alert*, and the *color red*, which may be different numeric constants, too. Without strong type guarantees, it is conceivable that one ends up using the alert numeric constant when one really wants to e.g. set a *red color* on a display. Or, with integer conversions and a lax function declaration, it is conceivable that someone ends up using something like `yellow|red` to get orange.

None of that is possible, so what exactly are we defending against?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> foo(a);   // not ambigious: E1 expected, nothing but E1::a possible

The type of the expression must be known. And since the use of `a` as a free-standing expression is ambiguous, the use of `a` anywhere is ambiguous.

You don't want expressions to change their meaning depending on the context they're used in. `1 + 1` always means the same thing. `1 + t` always means the same thing if you use the same `t`. Similarly, `a` should always mean the same thing no matter where it is used.

The only thing in C++ that allow for the deduction of the source type based on the context in which it is used is uniform initialization. And the standard explicitly states that a "braced-init-list" is *not* an expression. `a` is an expression, so it follows the expression rules.