# Why is it is impossible to overload return type in C++, but possible to overload parameters?

Tags: c++, overloading

I was wondering, is there a real technical limitation in the C++ compiler (or whatever) that causes that the return type cannot be overloaded, or is it just a design limitation inserted into the language?

Thanks!

Comment: Well how would the compiler know which one to choose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function overloading by return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

Comment: @Stefan It’s absolutely possible. Java does it. C++ can too, with a trick.

Comment: assigning to return value from function is optional so shouldn't consider for overloading

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: A call of a function with overloaded return type in a context where the return value can't be determined from the context would simply be an ambiguous function call, requiring an explicit disambiguation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't believe Java allows you to overload two method s with the different return types  unless the parameters are also different.

Comment: @W.K.S True, I misremember. What it *does* allow is generic type inference based on the return type. This is different, but a similar challenge for the compiler to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a technical limitation, if you want to call it that:

C++ types are inferred bottom-up: the type of an expression only depends on its sub-expressions, and not of the context expression(s) it appears in. So the type of the arguments of an overloaded method can be determined in order to pick which version to call, but it would be impossible to tell which method to call if there was overloading on the return type.

Example: in `e1 + f(e2, e3)`, the types of `e2` and `e3` can be determined before the version of `f` is chosen, and indeed the version of `f` is only then chosen according to them. But the context does not allow to pick a version of `f` according to its return type, and indeed, several types would be acceptable as return types.

Comment: I'd not call it a technical limitation. While the compiler indeed works the way you describe, it does so because the standard requires it to do so. The language could have been designed to allow overloading on the return type, and if done right, it would be no problem for compilers to add that capability to compilers. So I'd say it's a design limitation inserted into language.

Comment: It is, sadly. It's for that same reason that C++11 enums must be explicitly scope-resolved [when it's actually superfluous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13293439/572743) because it is obvious what the type must be. Since the language is defined in such a way (bottom-up), it limits itself sometimes.

Comment: @Damon: On the other hand, for user-defined conversion operators, the compiler effectively does overloading on return type. So there's no principal reason why it cannot be done more generally. The only restriction I see that overloading on return type would have to be a "second-class" overloading, only done after the parameter-based overloading has been performed, and if there's still an ambiguity, and can be done only in those cases where there's enough context (especially it would not work if used as argument to a function which itself is overloaded; that's basically the class enum issue).

Answer (score 1):

A function call is an expression.  Each expression has a context that effects how an expression is evaluated, but this information is not used in function overload resolution.

During function overload resolution the argument expressions of the function call are compared against the parameter declarations of the set of functions found when the function name is looked up.  Through an extremely complicated ranking algorithm, this selects the best viable function, and then the return type of the function gives the initial type of the function call expression.  Then, this return type is compared to the context to determine if a conversion is required (and if so, if it is possible and unambiguous) to adjust the return type to fit the context.

However these contexts are not simply specified by a type.  Each context is specified by its own unique set of rules in the standard.  So it would be extremely complicated to do overload resolution based on them.

Consider for example:

```
f(g(x))
```

Here we are doing overload resolution on `f` and `g`.  Suppose there are 10 versions of each function- and suppose we include the context of `g(x)` in overload resolution.

`g(x)` is an argument to `f` - so the context is "initialize one of ten different parameter types of ten different functions".

`x` is an argument being compared against the 10 `g` parameter lists.

So we would have to consider every possible combination of `f` and `g`, for a total of 100 combinations.

It's easy to see how such a scheme grows exponentially.  Now consider:

```
f(g(h(p(x))))
```

That is why in C++ function overload resolution is done in two steps.  For the example `f(g(x))`

1. First the `g` is selected based on `x`
2. Then the type T of `g(x)` is determined
3. Then `f` is selected based on `T`

Comment: And return type overloading could be done by adding another step: Currently, if after step 3 there's still an ambiguity in `f`, overload resolution fails. Instead, as fourth step, it could look at the context of the call, and *if that context provides enough information* (for `g(f(x))`: if `g` is neither overloaded nor templated on the argument) would select `f` based on the return type. That's still less general than the complete search, but would avoid the exponential growth issue.

Comment: @celtschk: Not including the context in the ranking algorithm along with the arguments/parameters is no longer really overloading based on context.  You can already implement your desired solution by [using a set of user-defined conversion operators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/226251/1131467).

Comment: You are aware of the no true scotsman fallacy? Because that's what you do here: You claim that it's not "true" overloading based on context if the context dependent step is only done after the argument dependent step. That you use the term "really" instead of "true" makes it no less an instance of the fallacy. As long as the the result of overload resolution depends on the context, you have context dependent overload resolution. And the fact that it already can be (mostly) emulated using user-defined conversion operators just proves that it could be implemented.

Comment: @celtschk: Ok, it depends what your definition of "context dependent overload resolution" is.  For some general definitions it isn't possible to do efficiently, for other more limited definitions it is.  Regardless of the definitions, I think we have both explored the issues successfully.